# WordPress Bimber template not sending User activation mails automatically

Tags: wp-mail, activation

[image]

I have a bimber WordPress template, it has a User section in admin panel, when a new user signups, it goes to pending section, waiting for me to send an activation mail. How can I automate this process?

Can I do it from WordPress menu?

Comment: You'll have to ask Bimber's support team. Third-party plugin & theme support is [off topic](/help/on-topic) here.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a plugin 'New User Approve'. It should approve automatically
OR
you can add a WordPress code in your Theme `functions.php` file; better you leave this code in a custom plugin to avoid the dependency to the Theme.

```php
function auto_activate_users($user_id) {
    $user = new WP_User($user_id);
    $user->set_role('subscriber'); // You can set the user role here.
}
add_action('user_register', 'auto_activate_users');
```

Answer (score 0):

To automate user activation emails in the Bimber WordPress theme:

Check the theme settings for any options related to user registration and activation.
Ensure that "Anyone can register" is enabled in WordPress settings under "Settings" > "General."
If needed, consider using a plugin like "WP User Activation" for additional customization or contact the theme's support for guidance.